# Block HTML tags in posts

Tags: php, javascript

Forums on the internet can block people from posting HTML tags in their posts. how is that done in php? I mean HTML tags show up as is in the tweets on twitter and in the comment space on Facebook? How is that done?

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is your friend. It will encode characters with a special meaning (`<`, `>`, `&`, and `"`) to their HTML entity equivalents (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, and `&quot;` respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) did the job very nicely. It required me to do some more processing, like creating a new function that would convert the HTML entity equivalents back into special chars.

Answer (score 0):

On the backend, you can use strip tags
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: `strip_tags` completely removes the html tags and thus not what was asked for. As jensgram said, `htmlspecialchars` is the one to use.